# Simultaneous if/else events in Processing

Tags: if-statement, processing, midi, state-machine

This program will take the specified MIDI INPUT device, and split its signals (regardless of channel) between channels 1-4 of the specified MIDI OUTPUT device depending on how many signals are being sent simultaneously.

This means that if you use a MIDI keyboard as the INPUT device, and you press any single key on the keyboard, that data will be sent to channel 1 on the OUTPUT device. BUT, if you press (or are EVER pressing) any 2 keys on the keyboard simultaneously, the first key you pressed will be sent to channel 1 while the second key you pressed will be sent to channel 2. The program will use this same process for up to 4 simultaneous notes (hence the 4 output channels).

A MIDI keyboard is not needed to do this, just download a virtual keyboard like VMPK (http://vmpk.sourceforge.net), and create a virtual port with something like loopMIDI (https://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/loopmidi.html) to connect the virtual keyboard to the script. If you use these two programs, make a virtual port with loopMIDI, and then open VMPK and set its output to the virtual port you just created.

The only problem, happens if you are playing multiple keys at a time, only release one of the keys (and continue holding the rest), and then try to press the key you released again. It does not send the message to a free channel, but it instead tries to send the message to a channel that is already busy.

EX: If you press one key and hold it down, if `notesPlayed = 0` the program sends the notes ON signal to channel 1 and sets `notesPlayed = notesPlayed + 1`, and then waits for you to let go of the key before sending the notes OFF signal to the same channel followed by setting `notesPlayed = notesPlayed - 1`.

So, if you aren't touching the keyboard (`notesPlayed = 0`), and then you begin holding a key (`notesPlayed = 1`) and begin holding another key (now `notesPlayed = 2`), and let go of the first key (now `notesPlayed = 1` again), and then try to press a key, it attempts to send it to channel 2 because `notesPlayed = 1`, but fails because channel 2 is still playing a note. I am racking my brain on how to fix this!

I presume there needs to be something like

```java
if (notesPlayed == 1) {                  // if 1 note is currently being played
     if (stat2 = 1) {                     // if channel 2 is already busy
"send note to the last available channel"
         }
 }
```

**Here is the program.**

```java
import controlP5.*;
import themidibus.*;
import at.mukprojects.console.*;


Console console;
ControlP5 cp5;
MidiBus myBus;
PFont sans;
final int MODE_1 = 1;
final int MODE_2 = 2;
int notesPlayed,ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4,stat1,stat2,stat3,stat4,mode,r,g,b;
String input = "NOT CONNECTED";
String output = "NOT CONNECTED";
String reset,devicesConnected;
boolean showConsole;

void setup()  {
  size(300, 550);
  smooth();
  notesPlayed = 0;
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  cp5.addTextfield("input").setPosition(10, 365).setSize(80, 20).setAutoClear(false);
  cp5.addTextfield("output").setPosition(100, 365).setSize(80, 20).setAutoClear(false);
  cp5.addBang("submit").setPosition(190, 365).setSize(20, 20);
  cp5.addBang("reset").setPosition(270, 365).setSize(20, 20);
  console = new Console(this);
  console.start();
  showConsole = true;
  mode = MODE_1;
  sans = loadFont("SansSerif.plain-18.vlw");
  reset = "yes";
  devicesConnected = "no";
  r = 255;
  g = 0;
  b = 0;
}

void draw(){

  background(0);

  switch(mode) {
  case MODE_1:
// (x, y, width, height, preferredTextSize, minTextSize, linespace, padding, strokeColor, backgroundColor, textColor)
    console.draw(2, 0, 295, 360, 13, 13, 1, 1);
    break;

  case MODE_2:
// (x, y, width, height, preferredTextSize, minTextSize, linespace, padding, strokeColor, backgroundColor, textColor)
    console.draw(2, 0, 295, 360, 13, 13, 1, 1, color(220), color(0), color(0, 255, 0));
    break;
  }

  textSize(12);
  fill(200, 200, 200);
  text("INPUT:", 10, 420);
  text("OUTPUT:", 10, 435);
  fill(r, g, b);
  text(input, 70, 420);
  text(output, 70, 435);

  fill(255, 255, 0);
  textSize(28);
  text("Channel Activity", 15, 450);

  textSize(60);

  if (stat1 == 0)  {
    fill(90, 90, 90);
    text("1", 20, 485);
  }

  if (stat2 == 0)  {
    fill(90, 90, 90);
    text("2", 95, 485);
  }

  if (stat3 == 0)  {
    fill(90, 90, 90);
    text("3", 170, 485);
  }

  if (stat4 == 0)  {
    fill(90, 90, 90);
    text("4", 245, 485);
  }

  if (stat1 == 1)  {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    text("1", 20, 485);
  }

  if (stat2 == 1)  {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    text("2", 95, 485);
  }

  if (stat3 == 1)  {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    text("3", 170, 485);
  }

  if (stat4 == 1)  {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    text("4", 245, 485);
  }

  textFont(sans);
  fill(r, g, b);
  textSize(14);
  text("- Active Devices -", 10, 405);

  if (reset == "yes")  {
    println(" ");
    println(" ");
    println(" ");
    println(" ");
    println(" ");
    println(" ");
    println(" ");
    println(" ");
    println(" ");
    println(" ");
    MidiBus.findMidiDevices();
    MidiBus.list();
    println("------------------------------------");
    println("      Input device names below");
    println("          (case sensitive)");
    input = "NOT CONNECTED";
    output = "NOT CONNECTED";
    r = 255;
    g = 0;
    b = 0;
    reset = "no";
  }  else  {}
}

void noteOn(int channel, int pitch, int velocity) {

  if (notesPlayed == 0)  {
    myBus.sendNoteOn(0, pitch, velocity);
    ch1 = pitch;
    stat1 = 1;
    println("CH1 - ON  - ", pitch, " ", velocity);
  }

  if (notesPlayed == 1) {
    myBus.sendNoteOn(1, pitch, velocity);
    ch2 = pitch;
    stat2 = 1;
    println("CH2 - ON  - ", pitch, " ", velocity);
  }

  if (notesPlayed == 2)  {
    myBus.sendNoteOn(2, pitch, velocity);
    ch3 = pitch;
    stat3 = 1;
    println("CH3 - ON  - ", pitch, " ", velocity);
  }

  if (notesPlayed == 3)  {
    myBus.sendNoteOn(3, pitch, velocity);
    ch4 = pitch;
    stat4 = 1;
    println("CH4 - ON  - ", pitch, " ", velocity);
  }

  notesPlayed = notesPlayed + 1;

}

void noteOff(int channel, int pitch, int velocity) {

  if (ch1 == pitch)  {
    myBus.sendNoteOff(0, pitch, velocity);
    stat1 = 0;
    println("CH1 - OFF - ", pitch, " ", velocity);
  }

    if (ch2 == pitch)  {
    myBus.sendNoteOff(1, pitch, velocity);
    stat2 = 0;
    println("CH2 - OFF - ", pitch, " ", velocity);
  }

    if (ch3 == pitch)  {
    myBus.sendNoteOff(2, pitch, velocity);
    stat3 = 0;
    println("CH3 - OFF - ", pitch, " ", velocity);
  }

    if (ch4 == pitch)  {
    myBus.sendNoteOff(3, pitch, velocity);
    stat4 = 0;
    println("CH3 - OFF - ", pitch, " ", velocity);
  }

  notesPlayed = notesPlayed - 1;

}

void submit()  {

  if (devicesConnected == "yes")  {
    println("There are already devices connected! Please reset first and try again.");
  }  else  {
    r = 0;
    g = 255;
    b = 0;
    input = cp5.get(Textfield.class,"input").getText();
    output = cp5.get(Textfield.class,"output").getText();
    myBus = new MidiBus(this, input, output);
    devicesConnected = "yes";
    mode = MODE_2;
  }
}

void reset()  {
  if (devicesConnected == "yes")  {
    myBus.close();
    devicesConnected = "no";
    mode = MODE_1;
  }  else  {}
  println(" ");
  println(" ");
  println(" ");
  println(" ");
  println(" ");
  println(" ");
  println(" ");
  println(" ");
  println(" ");
  println(" ");
  MidiBus.findMidiDevices();
  MidiBus.list();
  println("------------------------------------");
  println("      Input device names below");
  println("          (case sensitive)");
  input = "NOT CONNECTED";
  output = "NOT CONNECTED";
  r = 255;
  g = 0;
  b = 0;
  mode = MODE_1;
}
```

Comment: You'll have much better luck if you post a [mcve] instead of your whole program.

Comment: That being said, the way you'd handle this with a regular keyboard is to keep track of a boolean for each key you cared about. When you detect a key press, then set that boolean to true. When you detect a key release, set it to false. That allows you to track multiple keys being held down at the same time.

Comment: That makes sense. So I'm just doing it all wrong by keeping track of them with integers?

Comment: I don't know if I'd say it was all wrong, especially because I don't know enough about midi hardware to recommend a full solution. I just know that the general approach to the kind of thing you're describing is usually handled with a set of boolean variables. You can check out [this tutorial](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input) (scroll down to the "handling multiple keys" section) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I should use booleans instead for a cleaner approach, but that alone unfortunately won't fix the problem I am having.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand exactly how your code works, because I've never worked with midi hardware before. That's part of the reason I've been asking for a [mcve] (on this question and your previous question). If I knew when each function was being called, I'd be able to help. For example your question has nothing to do with ControlP5, so I'd recommend not including it in your example code. Like you discovered in your last question, complicated code like this takes longer to get an answer. But it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the current state of the system is determined by a single counter (`notesPlayed`); this does not allow you to determine which of the four outputs is currently active.

You need to have four independent states for the four outputs.
In other words, create an array with four entries; when a note-on message is received, search for the first free entry in the array; when a note-off message is received, search for the matching entry with the same note in the array.